# How to merge or push to an $.param array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made a serialized array/ object using:

`var data = $.param([{name: "commentID", value: commentID}, {name: "comment", value: comment}])`

Then later on before my Ajax request I need to add another $.param array, how can I do this? I tried $.merge but it messes up the array?

Comment: the result of $.param is a serialised string, not an array. Ideally, try and re-arrange your code so you don't serialise the array using this function until the last possible moment before you transmit it, or if you can't do that, then to be completely safe you'd probably have to unserialise it back to an array, push the item into it, and serialise back again. More naively you could just add another querystring-style parameter onto the end of `data` but you need to make sure you encode it properly in that case. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: Oh right ok, so is it bad to just use $.extend() then to add the extra data on?

Comment: @ADyson Is right, you should keep your data as an object/array until you send it. This make it easier to work with.

Comment: @Erdss4 it's not "bad", more like "impossible". You can't extend a string as if it was an array. I can't think of any reason to run $.param until the moment you are actually making the ajax request. If you delay until then, this problem simply goes away.

Comment: @ADyson Its because of the way other developers have past in the data, they have used $.param first on the function call and some data needs to be added before it goes off. The best thing would be to change it and delay it like you said but for now I need a quick update.

Comment: the simplest solution is probably what Himam has suggested, then. It feels like a dirty hack, but if you plan to refactor it later, then it might be adequate as a quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
var data = $.param([{name: "commentID", value: commentID}, {name: "comment", value: comment}]);

var newData = $.param([{name: "newID", value: newID}]);

data = data + "&" + newData;
```

Another way to do is have an array and use $.param before ajax call,

```
var data = [{name: "commentID", value: commentID}, {name: "comment", value: comment}];

data.push({name: "newID", value: newID});
```

and at the end

```
data = $.param(data);
```

Comment: This works but I feel like this is not the correct way to do this?